# How to add the class name attribute to parent tag of label using Zend_Form_Decorator?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I tried so hard, but I could not make the decorator like below format for my form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form_wrapper">
        <div class="form_label">
            <!-- {{label}} -->
        </div>
        <div class="form_element">
            <!-- {{element}} -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .form_wrapper -->
    <div class="form_wrapper">
        <div class="form_label">
            <!-- {{label}} -->
        </div>
        <div class="form_element">
            <!-- {{element}} -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .form_wrapper -->
</form>
```

And When I try to set class is `form_label` for my `decorator`:

```
array('Label', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form_label'))
```

#### It always is:

```
<div>
    <label class="form_label">Title</label>
</div>
```

I need to move **`form_label`** class inside the **`label` tag** to parent element: **`div` tag** of it?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for your decorator:

```
array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form_element')),
array('Label', array('tag' => 'div', 'tagClass'=>'form_label')),
array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form_wrapper'))
```

The important part is:

```
'tagClass'=>'form_label'
```

Look at `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label::render()` for how it works

Comment: It works. Can you tell me why I need: `array('data' => 'HtmlTag')` and `array('row' => 'HtmlTag')`?